# Reading from Volume Mounted ConfigMap File in Kotlin

Tags: typescript, kotlin, kubernetes, configmap

I have a file (test.json) within a ConfigMap that I am unable to read in my Kotlin application. I am able to read it within a TypeScript application that is doing almost the same thing, so I do not think it is an issue with the ConfigMap setup, but rather how I am trying to access the file in Kotlin. Here are my implementations:

ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
data:
  test.json: |-
    {
      "default": {
        "test1": true,
        "test2": true
      }
    }
```

Yaml file:

```
global:
  probe: false
  config:
    enabled: true
    configmap: "test-config"
    path: "/app/global"
    winPath: "c:\\app\\global"
  ... some other stuff
```

TypeScript Implementation to read from test.json during deployment: (This works with no problems and reads test.json)

```
const configMapPath = path.join(path.sep, 'app', 'global', 'test.json');
const fileData = fs.readFileSync(configMapPath);
```

Kotlin Implementation to read from test.json during deployment: (This does not work. Getting *FileNotFoundException* for path *\app\global\test.json*)

```
val configMapPath: Path = Paths.get("app", "global", "test.json")
val fileData: String = File(configMapPath.toString()).readText()
```

To me, it doesn't look like I am doing anything differently. Is there something different about the way files are read in from a ConfigMap in Java/Kotlin vs. TypeScript?

Comment: I don't know why your Kotlin implementation isn't working, but it could be because Kotlin is trying to read the file from a different location than where it is actually stored. Try printing out the value of configMapPath and see where it is pointing to.

Comment: configMapPath is /app/global/test.json. When I print out the absolute path, it points to my local file system (C:/users/myName/projects/projectName/app/global/test.json). The absolute file path is incorrect as it should be looking for the configMap, but I’m not sure that the method toAbsolutePath that I used makes sense in this context either.